# how to change wordpress' wp-login.php font to a custom font-family?

Tags: wordpress, fonts, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-font

I have uploaded a custom font to my wordpress site and changed the font family everywhere. However, the wp-login.php page's font will not change. I have tried editing the functions.php file multiple times but none of my changes take effect.

What I need is to have a custom font that I uploaded through a plugin, [Brainstorm Force's custom fonts plugin to be exact](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-fonts/), applied to my wp-login.php page

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. I uploaded the font files, linked them through font face in the main style stylesheet, and used the font family.

Edit:

1. I uploaded the font files much like an image is uploaded
2. Then I got the URL and added it in the stylesheet font-face section I implemented in the theme functions file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).